# What is actually being asked here?

Tags: questions

What is being asked in this question: "Do you have so much work that you need help?"

Is it asking, "Do you need help because you have so much work?"

Or, "Do you have so much work since you asked for help?"

Or is there another meaning?

Answer (score 0):

"Do you have so much work that you need help?" is asking the first question. It is *that* you have so much work that makes it so. "You need help" is directed at that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many meanings or uses of *that.*

From Oxford Languages:

> conjunction: **that**
>
> > expressing a result.
> >
> > > "she was so tired that she couldn't think"

Which means the same as "she couldn't think because she was so tired" or "she was so tired that, as a result, she couldn't think." But *as a result* is understood in this context, so it's superfluous. The same applies to your sample sentence.

Note: As worded (*so much*), it could possibly imply that the speaker thinks the subject does not have too much work and should not need any help. It depends on context and delivery.

Answer (score 0):

In English, the true, intended meaning of the speaker can be known only through the prosody of the speech. The same sentence can mean the opposite ideas depending on how the person says it. The literal meaning of the given sentence is to ask whether you have so much work to the degree that you need to ask help, However, to me, the sentence rather sounds sarcastic, that is, you don’t have that much work, so it is ridiculous that you are asking help from others. You might want to check out this lecture on how sarcasm is delivered:
https://www.nanheebyrnes.com/2023/02/degrees-of-pitch-rise-and-conveyed.html